# Run-time error when looping to return fonts in VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I am getting a "Run-time error -2147024809 (80070057), The specified value is out of range" error in the line:

```
Debug.Print (.TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name & " on slide number " & sld.SlideIndex) 'if not, report font and slide #
```

I am new to VBA in ppt. My code is to loop through a powerpoint and check that the text is written in Arial and if not, report that on the new first slide. The code works fine on a fresh ppt with just two mock slides I made, but now that I tested it on a real powerpoint I'm running the error. What object in a powerpoint will cause this?

```
Sub fonts()

'clear immediate window
For i = 0 To 100
    Debug.Print (vbCrLf)
Next i
Debug.Print ("module running..." & vbCrLf)


Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim str As String, str2 As String, font As String 'string and helper string
Dim msg
Dim response


'count of fonts in presentation
Debug.Print (ActivePresentation.fonts.Count & " font(s) in this presentation")

'getting font names in immediate window
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides 'for each slide
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes 'for each shape
        With shp
            If .TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name <> "Arial" Then 'check if font in shape is arial
                Debug.Print (.TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name & " on slide number " & sld.SlideIndex) 'if not, report font and slide #
            End If
        End With
    Next shp
Next sld


'putting font names into a string
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides 'for each slide
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes 'for each shape
        With shp
            If .TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name <> "Arial" Then 'check if font in shape is arial
            font = .TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name
                If str = "" Then
                    str = .TextFrame.TextRange.font.Name & " on slide number " & sld.SlideIndex & vbCrLf 'if string is blank, start string
                Else
                str2 = str
                str = str2 & font & " on slide number " & sld.SlideIndex & vbCrLf 'append to string
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next shp
Next sld

'adding a slide and pasting string to a text box there
If str <> "" Then
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
    Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
    Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout) 'adds slide to front of deck

    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=1, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=900, Height:=500).TextFrame _
    .TextRange.Text = str 'inserts textbox with string
    Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1) _
    .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.font _
    .Size = 16
Else
    msg = MsgBox("All fonts are Arial", vbOKOnly) 'popup box if all fonts in the presentation are ok
End If


Debug.Print (vbCrLf & "end of module")


End Sub
```

Comment: Since we have no access to this presentation it's really not possible for anyone else to know what the problem is. Probably, the `Shape` object does not support text - a picture, for example. You can `Debug.Print shp.Name` or perform `shp.Select`, then stop the macro code (set a breakpoint) and look at what it is. Probably, you should test `shp.Type` (returns a member of the `MsoShapeType` enumeration) before going to the `If`-block to make sure access the `Text` properties is supported by that `Shape`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. If it's the case, then I could run an if loop to only proceed when the shp.Type supports text, right?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, yes :-)

Comment: This statement checks for a text frame in the shape and whether that textframe contains any text:
If shp.HasTextFrame And shp.TextFrame2.HasText Then

Comment: Not related, but the if/else str, str2 juggling in the second "block", could be solved easier with `str = str & .....`